# MS BotFramework Sign-In Redirection fail in Messenger Webview

Tags: botframework, facebook-messenger

1. I made a Sign-In Card using the Microsoft Bot Framework.
2. The Sign-In button OpenURL to Login of Microsoft Graph
3. The user write it's credential
4. A message ask him to accept the Microsoft App
5. Then it is redirected to a thanks page (the access token si forwarded to my bot)

Issue:

- Using Messenger Webview it breaks at 5.)
- Using Desktop Messenger it works.
- Using Mobile Chrome (with the Sign-In URL copy/past) it works

The webview display the steps in the microsoft domain but the redirection to my server fails.

Is there kind of limitation with Messenger WebView ? Is there a Best Practice to sign-in throught Messenger ?

**EDIT:**

The code is [located in a Node-RED node](https://github.com/NGRP/node-red-contrib-viseo/blob/master/node-red-contrib-ms-graph/node-ms-graph-oauth.js).
The redirect is a standard Node-RED (aka ExpressJS) end point
The card construction relies on Microsoft Bot Builder v3.0

Comment: do you mind sharing your code constructing the card?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When building a Sign-In Card with Microsoft Graph authentication you have to add two platforms:
- Web Platform
- Native Platform

Set the Callback URL to the Web Platform and leave native platform as is with no custom redirection.

It should now works with Messenger App and Web App